# What are the key differences between model and migration definitions in Sequelize?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js, umzug

Some Sequelize users of SQL databases often use `sync({ force: true })` in the early days, and then switch over to migrations. I'm confused because the migrations and models seem to have a similar syntax, but also a number of differences that don't seem to be strongly highlighted.

Some observations (which may be wrong):

- the options objects in the two are different: `options.indexes` object in the model doesn't work in migrations (but works in models)
- Custom index names using `unique: 'somename'` doesn't work in the migration field attributes (but works in models); but a `unique: true` works in both
- foreign keys need to be explicitly created - and a `references` needs to be set in migrations (but in models, the hasMany/belongsTo automatically generates the foreign key field and foreign key reference)
- `id`, `createdAt` and `updatedAt` must be manually created in a migration, but not a model

The last two make sense as it's delineating the migration responsibilities (which sets up the db schema) versus the model - but what the migration supports/how it works seems different for similar items, and the `sync` option exacerbates my confusion.

Some questions:

- What are the main differences to keep in mind between migrations and models **in Sequelize** (not the general philosophy between the two)? What options in models (when using the `sync` option) *do* work in migrations?
- Do others simply copy model files into migrations when switching from `sync` to discrete migrations? Do you cut out parts of the extraneous info that only works in models? Only works in migrations?

Comment: Sync definitely makes some assumptions when creating the schema in regards to primary keys, constraints, associations and indexes. All of these assumptions/conveniences needs to be explicitly declared in the migration.

Comment: I would also be interested in a more detailed answer. As far as I understand it, the migration file will communicate with the database and only DB related things are usable. The model on the other hand, almost acts as a middleware before sending data to database. So getters and setters won't have any affect on a migration file, but will on a model file.